# Методология БЭМ. Правильно ли я понимаю?

Tags: вёрстка, бэм

```
<div class="c-catalog">
        <div class="c-catalog__header">Каталог</div>
        <div class="c-catalog__products">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="c-catalog__product">
                    <img src="img/product.jpg" class="c-catalog__product__img">
                    <p class="c-catalog__product__describe"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="c-catalog__product"></div>
                <div class="c-catalog__product"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="c-catalog__product"></div>
                <div class="c-catalog__product"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Любителям БЭМ-методологии, правильно ли я понимаю БЭМ?

Есть общий класс `c-catalog`.
Все остальные вложенные классы должны быть с префиксом `с-catalog`?

А если как в мое примере, появился `c-catalog__products`, то входящие в него элементы должны быть `с-catalog__product` или `с-catalog__products__item`?

И что если в разметке появляются элементы, которые никак не влияют на логику и структуры и нужны просто для оформления, типа `.wrapper`.

Это допускается, или его надо тоже именовать через `с-catalog`?

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

> Есть общий класс c-catalog. Все остальные вложенные классы должны быть
>   с префиксом с-catalog?

Так как *c-catalog* является **блоком**, а **блок** в БЭМ задаёт *пространство имён*, то его дочерние **элементы**, как правило, должны содержать префикс данного корневого **блока**.

Это правило именования не распространяется на *универсальные блоки* (см. ниже)

> А если как в мое примере, появился c-catalog__products, то входящие в
>   него элементы должны быть с-catalog__product или
>   с-catalog__products__item?

*c-catalog__products* в данном случае является **элементом** блока *c-catalog*, а элементы НЕ задают *пространство имён* в БЭМ. К тому же все дочерние элементы *c-catalog__products* так же являются дочерними элементами основного блока *c-catalog* и должны содержать его префикс **c-catalog**. Т.е. ответ на вопрос - c-catalog__product.

Подробнее о том, почему не рекомендуют использовать второй вариант *с-catalog__products__item* можно прочитать [здесь](https://ru.bem.info/faq/#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%AD%D0%9C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-block__elem1__elem2).

> И что если в разметке появляются элементы, которые никак не влияют на
>   логику и структуры и нужны просто для оформления, типа .wrapper.
>
> Это допускается, или его надо тоже именовать через с-catalog?

[Допускается](https://ru.bem.info/faq/#%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2), в данном случае *wrapper* является универсальным блоком.

Comment: а картинка c-catalog__product__img или c-catalog__product_img?

Comment: @ruslik c-catalog__img, так как картинка расположена в **блоке** c-catalog, а сама она является **элементом**.